# Map columns of two df based on array intersection of individual columns and based on highest common element Pandas Memory error Pyspark/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, pyspark

I have a dataframe df1 like this:

```
A   B
AA  [a,b,c,d]
BB  [a,f,g,c]
CC  [a,b,l,m]
```

And another one as df2 like:

```
C   D
XX  [a,b,c,n]
YY  [a,m,r,s]
UU  [e,h,I,j]
```

I want to find out and map column C of df2 with column A of df1 based on the highest element match between the items of df2['D'] and df1['B'] and null if there is none.

The result df will look like:

```
C      D         A   common_items
XX  [a,b,c,n]   AA    [a,b,c]
YY  [a,m,r,s]   CC    [a,m]
UU  [e,h,I,j]   Null    Null
```

The solution I have is to convert to set, compute the intersections with numpy and get the best match:

```
b = df1['B'].apply(set).to_numpy()
d = df2['D'].apply(set).to_numpy()

# compute pairwise intersections
common = d[:,None] & b

# get largest intersection per row
vlen = np.vectorize(len)
idx = np.argmax(vlen(common), axis=1)

# assign intersections and original ID
df2['common_items'] = common[np.arange(len(d)), idx]
df2['A'] = np.where(df2['common_items'].str.len()>0,
                    df1['A'].to_numpy()[idx], None)
```

Any solution on the number of common elements of the two columns of different dataframes, mapping the source df1['A'] to target df2['c'].
[a,b,c,d] etc are list of string.

Data:

```
df1.to_dict('list'):
{'A': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC'],
 'B': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'f', 'g', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'l', 'm']]}


df2.to_dict('list'):
{'C': ['XX', 'YY', 'UU'],
 'D': [['a', 'b', 'c', 'n'], ['a', 'm', 'r', 's'], ['e', 'h', 'l', 'j']]}
```

It's working fine for a limited amount of data (say 5K). When I am trying to do this between size of 87K as df2 and df1 as 567, it is constantly coming with memory outage error on databricks.

```
The spark driver has stopped unexpectedly and is restarting. Your notebook will be automatically reattached.
```

Anything efficient if not in Pandas, in Pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the dataframes are called `df1` and `df2`

```
# imports
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.window as W

# explode columns B and D of your dataframes
df1_exploded = df1.select('A', F.explode('B').alias('B'))
df2_exploded = df2.select('C', F.explode('D').alias('D'))

# join dataframes on B==D
df = df2_exploded.join(df1_exploded, on=F.col('B')==F.col('D'), how='left')

# flag the matches
df = df.withColumn('matches', F.when(F.col('B')==F.col('D'), F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(0)))

# count and collect the matches
df = df.groupby('C', 'A').agg(
    F.sum('matches').alias('matches'),
    F.collect_set('D').alias('common_items')
)

# rank the matches for each item in C
df = df.withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(W.Window.partitionBy('C').orderBy(F.col('matches').desc())))

# filter out the highest match for each item in C
df = df.where(F.col('rank')==1)

# join back with your original df2 to get the original column D
df = df.join(df2, on='C', how='inner').drop('matches', 'rank')
```

If your use case demands it a similar solution can be achieved in pandas as well. Equivalent of `F.explode()` in pandas is `df_A_exploded = df_A.explode("B")`. The rest of the operations are basic data wrangling operations that you shouldn't have any problem implementing in pandas.